# Legend overriding x-label and x-ticks

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have the following figure produced by plotting multiple subplots with a Pandas DataFrame:

[image]

You'll notice that the two subplots on the left do not have any x-ticks or x-labels.

Here is the code I use to plot the figure:

```
plt.suptitle(suptitle,fontsize=fs+6)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:8,0])
title = 'e1 on Object a'
plt.title('Bias vs Separation For ' + title,fontsize=fs)
plt.ylim([(min_mean - 2*min_s_mean)*min_offset,(max_mean + max_s_mean)*max_offset])
plt.xlabel('Separation (arcsec)',fontsize=fs)
plt.ylabel('Residual',fontsize=fs)
f_m_e1_a = format_df(means_e1_a,x_min,x_max,means_e1_a.index)
f_s_m_e1_a = format_df(s_means_e1_a,x_min,x_max,s_means_e1_a.index)
plt.legend(loc=0,prop={'size':leg_fs})
ax1p = f_m_e1_a.T.plot(ax=ax1,style=['k--o','b--o','g--o'],yerr=f_s_m_e1_a.T)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[11:19,0])
title = 'e1 on Object b'
plt.title('Bias vs Separation For ' + title,fontsize=fs)
plt.ylim([(min_mean - 2*min_s_mean)*min_offset,(max_mean + max_s_mean)*max_offset])
plt.xlabel('Separation (arcsec)',fontsize=fs)
plt.ylabel('Residual',fontsize=fs)
f_m_e1_b = format_df(means_e1_b,x_min,x_max,means_e1_b.index)
f_s_m_e1_b = format_df(s_means_e1_b,x_min,x_max,s_means_e1_b.index)
plt.legend(loc=0,prop={'size':leg_fs})
ax2p = f_m_e1_b.T.plot(ax=ax2,style=['k--o','b--o','g--o'],yerr=f_s_m_e1_b.T)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:8,1])
title = 'e2 on Object a'
plt.title('Bias vs Separation For ' + title,fontsize=fs)
plt.ylim([(min_mean - 2*min_s_mean)*min_offset,(max_mean + max_s_mean)*max_offset])
plt.xlabel('Separation (arcsec)',fontsize=fs)
plt.ylabel('Residual',fontsize=fs)
f_m_e2_a = format_df(means_e2_a,x_min,x_max,means_e2_a.index)
f_s_m_e2_a = format_df(s_means_e2_a,x_min,x_max,means_e2_a.index)
plt.legend(loc=0,prop={'size':leg_fs})
ax3p = f_m_e2_a.T.plot(ax=ax3,style=['k--o','b--o','g--o'],yerr=f_s_m_e2_a.T)

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[11:19,1])
title = 'e2 on Object b'
plt.title('Bias vs Separation For ' + title,fontsize=fs)
plt.ylim([(min_mean - 2*min_s_mean)*min_offset,(max_mean + max_s_mean)*max_offset])
plt.xlabel('Separation (arcsec)',fontsize=fs)
plt.ylabel('Residual',fontsize=fs)
f_m_e2_b = format_df(means_e2_b,x_min,x_max,means_e2_b.index)
f_s_m_e2_b = format_df(s_means_e2_b,x_min,x_max,s_means_e2_b.index)
plt.legend(loc=0,prop={'size':leg_fs})
ax4p = f_m_e2_b.T.plot(ax=ax4,style=['k--o','b--o','g--o'],yerr=f_s_m_e2_b.T)
```

I'm doing the same thing for all the plots yet the why are the two on the left not showing x-ticks and x-labels?

I instantiate a gridspec object for use and the figure but that's all.

It's also not setting the style to be as I specified, which is exterior to the issue at hand.

Comment: Is that really a minimal example? You can't take out any of those (repeated!) lines of layout code without the problem going away?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example *with* data. The code you posted can not be run as the dataframes are missing.

Comment: This is the second question that I have seen go by this week that boils down to 'df.plot is nuking my xticks'.  I suspect that this is a bug in pandas. also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524951/python-xticks-disapearing-in-subplot